# Tensor equation problem (xact package)

Tags: equation-solving, tensors, xact

So i want to solve the tensor equation P1[-μ,-ν]=0 with respect to A[r] and then B[r] but the problem is when hitting shift-enter the tensor given is way too long (if i press "show all" my computer crashes so i cant see the whole result) and dsolve or ndsolve didnt work. Are there any recommendations as to how i can find A and B any other commands, or at least plot them? g(R) is the Ricci Scalar and the manifold is [M4, 4, {μ, ν, α, β, σ, λ, b, c, d, e, f}]. Also the metric is the diag{-1/B[r],1/A[r],r^2,r^2*[sinθ]^2} matrix.Thank you in advance.

```
    DefTensor[P1[-μ, -ν], M4]
    IndexSet[P1[μ_, 
      ν_], (-96*a*
          met[μ, ν] ((Ricci[CD][-α, f]) (Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][-β, 
              λ]) (Ricci[CD][-f, -λ])) + 
         24*a*met[μ, 
           ν]*((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (Ricci[CD][α, 
              β]) (Ricci[CD][-f, -λ]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ])) - 
         Ricci[CD][μ, ν] + 
         320*a*((Ricci[CD][-α, f]) (Ricci[CD][α, 
              β]) (Ricci[CD][-β, -f]) (Ricci[CD][μ, ν])) + 
         1/2*met[μ, ν]*(g[r[]]) + 
         160/3*a*met[μ, 
           ν]*((Ricci[CD][-α, f]) (Ricci[CD][α, 
              β]) (Ricci[CD][-β, -f]) (g[r[]])) - 
         352*a*((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][μ, 
              ν]) (g[r[]])) - 
         8*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (Ricci[CD][α, β]) ((g[r[]])^2)) + 
         48*a*((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) ((g[r[]])^3)) + 
         1/6*a*met[μ, ν] ((g[r[]])^4) + 
         256*a*((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ]) (Ricci[CD][μ, 
              ν]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -f, -β, -λ])) - 
         16*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ]) (g[
              r[]]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -f, -β, -λ])) + 
         32*a*((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (g[
              r[]]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]) (Riemann[CD][α, β, f, 
              λ])) - 
         7*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((g[r[]])^2 (Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]) (Riemann[CD][α, β,
               f, λ])) - 
         48*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -f, b,
               c]) (Riemann[CD][-β, -λ, -b, -c])) - 
         48*a*((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -β, b, c]) (Riemann[CD][
              α, β, f, λ]) (Riemann[CD][-f, -λ, -b, -c])) + 
         12*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((g[r[]]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -β, b, c]) (Riemann[CD][α, β, f, 
              λ]) (Riemann[CD][-f, -λ, -b, -c])) + 
         32*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ]) (Riemann[CD][-α, b, -β,
               c]) (Riemann[CD][-f, -b, -λ, -c])) + 
         8*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (Ricci[CD][α, 
              β]) (Riemann[CD][-f, -λ, -b, -c]) (Riemann[CD][f, λ, b, 
              c])) - 1/2*a*
          met[μ, ν] ((Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]) (Riemann[CD][α, β, f, 
              λ]) (Riemann[CD][-b, -c, -d, -e]) (Riemann[CD][b, c, d, 
              e])) + 16*
          a*((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (g[r[]]) (CD[-α]@CD[α]@g[r[]])) - 
         8*a*met[μ, ν] ((g[r[]])^2) (CD[-α]@CD[α]@g[r[]]) + 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][β, f]) (Ricci[CD][ν, α]) (CD[-α]@
              CD[μ]@Ricci[CD][-β, -f])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][ν, α]) (Riemann[CD][β, f, λ, b]) (CD[-α]@
              CD[μ]@Riemann[CD][-β, -f, -λ, -b])) + 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][β, f]) (Ricci[CD][μ, α]) (CD[-α]@
              CD[ν]@Ricci[CD][-β, -f])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, α]) (Riemann[CD][β, f, λ, b]) (CD[-α]@
              CD[ν]@Riemann[CD][-β, -f, -λ, -b])) + 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (CD[-α][g[r[]]]) (CD[α][g[r[]]])) - 
         8*a*met[μ, ν] ((g[r[]]) (CD[-α][g[r[]]]) (CD[α][g[r[]]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][ν, -α]) (g[r[]]) (CD[α]@CD[μ]@g[r[]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, -α]) (g[r[]]) (CD[α]@CD[ν]@g[r[]])) - 
         64*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (CD[-α][Ricci[CD][f, λ]]) (CD[-β][
              Ricci[CD][-f, -λ]])) - 
         16*a ((Riemann[CD][μ, α, ν, β]) (CD[-α][
              Riemann[CD][f, λ, b, c]]) (CD[-β][
              Riemann[CD][-f, -λ, -b, -c]])) - 
         16*a ((Riemann[CD][f, λ, b, c]) (Riemann[CD][μ, α, ν, 
              β]) (CD[-β]@CD[-α]@Riemann[CD][-f, -λ, -b, -c])) + 
         16*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (CD[α][g[r[]]]) (CD[β][g[r[]]])) - 
         16*a ((Riemann[CD][μ, -α, ν, -β]) (CD[α][g[r[]]]) (CD[β][
              g[r[]]])) + 
         16*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][-α, -β]) (g[r[]]) (CD[β]@CD[α]@g[r[]])) - 
         8*a*((g[r[]]) (Riemann[CD][μ, -α, ν, -β]) (CD[β]@
              CD[α]@g[r[]])) - 
         8*a*((g[r[]]) (Riemann[CD][μ, -β, ν, -α]) (CD[β]@
              CD[α]@g[r[]])) - 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (CD[-f]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) + 
         32*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (g[r[]]) (CD[-f]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) - 
         64*a*((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (CD[-f][Ricci[CD][-α, -β]]) (CD[f][
              Ricci[CD][α, β]])) + 
         32*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((g[r[]]) (CD[-f][Ricci[CD][-α, -β]]) (CD[f][
              Ricci[CD][α, β]])) - 
         64*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Ricci[CD][f, λ]) (CD[-λ]@
              CD[-f]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) + 
         64*a*((Riemann[CD][μ, -f, ν, -λ]) (CD[f][
              Ricci[CD][α, β]]) (CD[λ][Ricci[CD][-α, -β]])) + 
         32*a ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Riemann[CD][μ, -f, ν, -λ]) (CD[λ]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) + 
         32*a ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Riemann[CD][μ, -λ, ν, -f]) (CD[λ]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) + 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -f, -β, -λ]) (CD[λ]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][α, β])) - 
         32*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((g[r[]]) (Riemann[CD][-α, -f, -β, -λ]) (CD[λ]@
              CD[f]@Ricci[CD][α, β])) + 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, ν]) (CD[-b][
              Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]]) (CD[b][
              Riemann[CD][α, β, f, λ]])) - 
         8*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((g[r[]]) (CD[-b][Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]]) (CD[b][
              Riemann[CD][α, β, f, λ]])) + 
         64*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (Riemann[CD][f, λ, b, c]) (CD[-c]@
              CD[-λ]@Riemann[CD][-α, -f, -β, -b])) + 
         64*a*met[μ, 
           ν] ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (CD[-b][
              Riemann[CD][-β, -λ, -f, -c]]) (CD[c][
              Riemann[CD][-α, f, λ, b]])) + 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][ν, α]) (CD[-α][Ricci[CD][-β, -f]]) (CD[μ][
              Ricci[CD][β, f]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][ν, -α]) (CD[α][g[r[]]]) (CD[μ][g[r[]]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][ν, α]) (CD[-α][
              Riemann[CD][-β, -f, -λ, -b]]) (CD[μ][
              Riemann[CD][β, f, λ, b]])) - 
         32*a ((g[r[]]) (CD[μ][Ricci[CD][α, β]]) (CD[ν][
              Ricci[CD][-α, -β]])) + 
         64*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, α]) (CD[-α][Ricci[CD][-β, -f]]) (CD[ν][
              Ricci[CD][β, f]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, -α]) (CD[α][g[r[]]]) (CD[ν][g[r[]]])) + 
         8*a ((g[r[]]) (CD[μ][g[r[]]]) (CD[ν][g[r[]]])) + 
         8*a ((g[r[]]) (CD[μ][Riemann[CD][α, β, f, λ]]) (CD[ν][
              Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]])) - 
         16*a ((Ricci[CD][μ, α]) (CD[-α][
              Riemann[CD][-β, -f, -λ, -b]]) (CD[ν][
              Riemann[CD][β, f, λ, b]])) - 
         32*a ((Ricci[CD][α, β]) (g[r[]]) (CD[ν]@
              CD[μ]@Ricci[CD][-α, -β])) + 
         8*a (((g[r[]])^2) (CD[ν]@CD[μ]@g[r[]])) + 
         8*a ((g[r[]]) (Riemann[CD][α, β, f, λ]) (CD[ν]@
              CD[μ]@Riemann[CD][-α, -β, -f, -λ]))) // 
       BasisExpand[#, polar] & // FromBasisExpand[#, {polar, polar}]]
```

Comment: I did not try to understand the details of the code but the xTras package has [SolveConstants](http://www.xact.es/xTras/documentation/ref/SolveConstants.html) and [SolveTensors](http://www.xact.es/xTras/documentation/ref/SolveTensors.html) which might be of interest to you. Also maybe see the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3493) for xTras on arxiv

Comment: thank you a lot i will try it!!

Comment: (:. I should mention that xTras uses xAct. I do not remember if xTras comes with xAct when xAct is downloaded. The functions I mentioned seem to work with linear systems and I do not know if it can solve non linear systems. From an error message in an example in the documentation of SolveConstants in the links above, it seems that SolveConstants  uses `Solve` so maybe it can solve non linear systems but I do not know. I also do not know what methods SolveTensors use but it seems, from my vague understanding of the situation, that your case might be adapted to SolveConstants.